# Converting dictionary parameters into inline json request

Tags: python-2.7

I am writing a python script to try and access a web service using an API . Unfortunately the API documentation lacks some details and examples on how to make the request.

I have been able to make the requests using curl and now I want to use python to make the requests. I am using python 2.7.5 and using the requests module to access to end.

Please note this appears to be a get request rather than a post request.

Below is my curl command which works correctly

```
curl -k -s --cookie-jar session_cookie "https://example.com8001?\{\"request\":\"login\",\"data\":\{\"login\":\"user-account\",\"password\":\"super-secret-password\"\}\}"
```

When I try to translate that in python and using a dictionary I have the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import json
import logging
import socket
import requests
import urllib
import os

## Stop bugging me about insecure stuff
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

username = "user-account"
password = "super-secret-password"

custom_headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

server = socket.gethostname()
port = "8001"

spurl = "https://%s:%s" % (server, port)
spurl2 = 'https://%s:%s?{"request":"login","data":{"login":"user-account","password":"super-secret-password"}}'% (server, port)

r1 = requests.get(spurl2,  headers=custom_headers, verify=False)
```

Now that works pretty well if I craft the URL by hand but I don't want to do that. Any idea how I convert the dictionary object into the inline json request?

Thanks in advance.

-Nigel

Comment: I guess you tried `spurl = "https://%s:%s?%s" % (server, port, json.dumps(params))` ?

Comment: I have tried that unfortunately without success.

Comment: Ok then check that : https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1159/ but it's really bad practice to pass a JSON in a GET param imo

Comment: Thanks, I'll have look at that and see if that helps.

Comment: It's also bad practice to use GET to send secrets: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/147188/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-get-method-as-login-username-password-for-administrato